# Visual Studio 2013 - Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, debugging

I am experiencing an issue with debugging SharePoint 2013 Workflows in a SharePoint App solution:

[image: Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete. Would you like to disable workflow debugging in order to debug other parts of this project? Workflows will still be installed but will not have debugging support. (You can re-enable workflow debugging later from Project Properties page - SharePoint tab.)]

Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Are you developing an App? If so, I may have an idea.

Comment: Yes, a Provider Hosted App.

Comment: Umm. Ok, try to create the App package by using the "Publish" command in visual studio. I have seen that message appearing when you try to debug and the package has not been created before (know it is strange, but we are speaking of Visual Studio...)

Comment: It's definitely creating the App package and deploying as expected. If I turn off Workflow debugging, everything deploys and functions as expected (except I cannot debug my Workflow).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist publishing the app worked! Sorry for doubting you! Answer the question so I can give you some reputation points :)

Comment: Done. Also sorry for not replying before. I **had** posted a "Please, trust me and give it a chance." message before, but some Internet Gremlin must have eaten it.

Comment: (I have also edited the question to more directly reference App development - as far as I know the bug is only experienced for apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As strange as it may seem, this error is often experienced when you are debugging a SharePoint App and you never had published your solution (so the solution package has not been created).
Use the "Publish" command to create the package and debugging should work normally afterward.

Notice that the deploy functionality works even without the publish step so that could create some confusion.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but this answer has not solved the issue. I have provided more info on my problem here: [Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete - VS2013 Autohosted App](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89657/workflow-debugging-prerequisites-failed-to-complete-vs2013-autohosted-app). Please take a look and share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: @Perisdr I believe that the main difference is that you are running against SP Online. I will check if anything comes to mind, but I cannot promise.

Comment: According to this [Debugging SharePoint 2013 workflows using Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/10/30/debugging-sharepoint-2013-workflows-using-visual-studio-2013.aspx) you can have debugging of workflows in SharePoint Online. I have successfully debugged remote events in my project using azure service bus. Maybe my VS 2013 isn't properly set up? Or my site-collection? Can't think of anything else