# Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete - VS2013 Autohosted App

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, debugging

I am creating an auto-hosted app on VS2013. I am working with **SharePoint Online** and not locally. The problem is that when I try to enable the workflow debugging on my project I receive the error:

> Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete. Would you like to disable workflow debugging in order to debug other parts id this project? Workflows will still be installed but will not have debugging support.
>
> (You can re-enable workflow debugging later from Project properties page - SharePoint tab.)

Since I do not have SharePoint installed locally I am pretty much not able to try something else. I cannot find info on this error on the net besides another stackexchange question:
[Visual Studio 2013 - Workflow debugging prerequisites failed to complete](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88851/visual-studio-2013-workflow-debugging-prerequisites-failed-to-complete)

But the solution provided there is not working for me.

Another thing I have noticed is a warning I get in my Error List window stating:

> Microsoft.Workflow.TestServiceHost.exe ended with error.

Now after many VS reboots I got another warning:

> SharePoint Configurator cannot be run as the connection to SharePoint site https://mysharepointonlinesite.sharepoint.com/sites/lab/ has not been initiated yet.

All these warnings aren't discussed on the net apparently because I still cannot find any other info on the subject.

Thank you for any input on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 1, I no longer receive the errors above. Maybe it will help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I edited my answer since my installation is out of date. It appears that they did add remote debugging to VS 2012 and 2013, if you're deploying an autohosted app. The link goes on to explain that you need a special access key (connection string) to remotely debug your workflows from the azure service. Please follow Perisdr's link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/10/30/debugging-sharepoint-2013-workflows-using-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: According to this [Debugging SharePoint 2013 workflows using Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/10/30/debugging-sharepoint-2013-workflows-using-visual-studio-2013.aspx) SharePoint Online is supported. Have you seen it somewhere official that it is not supported?